# Count months from datetime in MySQL with years

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I have been banging my head around trying to come up with a query to display a datetime to show years -> months -> count(months with that year).

Example:
I want to show my results like this:

```
Year    Mth     #
2012    Apr     595
2012    Mar     27
2011    Oct     1
etc...
```

my table looks like this:

```
create table `log` (
    `datetime` datetime ,
    `username` varchar (75),
    `clientaddr` varchar (225),
    `action` varchar (75),
    `details` varchar (300)
);
```

I want to show all the records in in the logs table as shown above. Anyone have any suggestions? Feel free to share an algorithm to do the same thing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how do you calculate the value of # i mean is that sum of clientaddr or something else ???

Comment: the value of # is the count of all the records with that month and year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
select year(datetime) as year, monthname(datetime) as month, count(*) from log group by year, month order by year, month;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YEAR(`DateTime`) AS Year, MONTH(`DateTime`) as Month, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Log
GROUP BY YEAR(`DateTime`), MONTHNAME(`DateTime`)
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

It is not recommended to use DateTime as a column name.